# Is there a way to disable UpdateProgress for certain async postbacks?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I have an UpdateProgress control, that shows as an overlay (using CSS) for all async events for an update panel. Now, for certain EXPAND/COLLAPSE row command events, i just dont want to show that updateprogress.

Is there a way?

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it sounds like you should be able to bind an event handler to whatever event fires the expand/collapse.  Is it a click event?  Post your code please.

Comment: Events are binding all right, it's just the UpdateProgress overlay that i don't want to show for certain RowCommand Events for gridview contained in that updatepanel

Comment: 1.) Use more than one UpdatePanel if possible. The UpdateProgress-Control has a property `AssociatedUpdatePanelID`. Set the ID to the UpdatePanel that the UpdateProgress displays status for and don't use an UpdateProgress-control for the UpdatePanel of the row commands.
2.) Play around with the `DisplayAfter` property that indicates when the UpdateProgress will be displayed. Maybe that is already enough. 3.) Trigger the UpdateProgress by yourself, have a look at [this link](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/125_Using_UpdateProgress_Control_Effectively.aspx) to see the techniques.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
        var updateProgress = $get('UpdateProgress1');
        var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
        if (postBackElement.id == '<%= Button1.ClientID %>') {
            updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId = 'dummyId';
        }
        else{
            updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId = null;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Superb. Well understood and correctly answered to the point. Thanks

Comment: This works once I have adjusted to **updateProgress[0].control._associatedUpdatePanelId**

Answer (score 0):

I found this works for me where a Response.Redirect prevents the original page being reloaded & therefore the UpdateProgress does not get turned off..

On the offending control add

```
OnClientClick="disableProgress()"
```

and then put this javascript on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function disableProgress() {

var updateProgress = $get('<%=UpdateProgress1.ClientID%>');
var originalID = updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId;
updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId = 'dummyId';

setTimeout(function () { updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId = originalID; }, 1000);

}
</script>
```

This temporarily disables the UpdateProgress control and then asynchronously reactivates it client-side after 1 second.