# Disable UpdateProgress in UpdatePanel with ASP Button OnClientClick

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a single UpdateProgress control in my UpdatePanel. In this UpdatePanel I have a MultiView. This MultiView has many buttons to navigate the different Views.

What I am trying to do is only show the UpdateProgress animation when a specific button is clicked. All other buttons should hide/disable the UpdateProgress control. I am attempting this through jQuery. I am open to any method though.

This is my current code:

```
 function hideProgress() {
    $('#<%= UpdateProgress.ClientID %>').hide();
    //console.log('hello');
    return false;
 }
```

Here is one of the buttons:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" OnClientClick="hideProgress()" />
```

I know I am getting into my function because I get my log message. There are no errors, it just doesn't work.

Can someone show me how I would accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you view the source code of the page when it is rendered, do the id's or UpdateProgress and UpdateProgress.ClientID match?

Comment: What if you just try `document.getElementById('<%= UpdateProgress.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the solution proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6301744/1071574.

In a nutshell, the idea is to associate the `UpdateProgress` control with a "dummy" (i.e. inexistent) `UpdatePanel` whenever you want to disable it, based on the control that generated the async postback. This will cause it never to show (since the only `UpdatePanel` it is supposed to work with doesn't exist).