# Disabled UpdateProgress for an entire page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have checked out this solution: [Is there a way to disable UpdateProgress for certain async postbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299072/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updateprogress-for-certain-async-postbacks)

But this disables my controls from loading at all!

I have an UpdateProgress in my master page that is triggered throughout the entire site, but on certain pages I would like for it to be disabled.

I don't want to prevent the control from loading, I just want to prevent UpdateProgress from popping up at all for a page load.

Comment: You should post some code please

Answer (score 2):

Update Progress renders as a DIV. E.g. if you have something like

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="xupProgress" runat="server"  >
  <ProgressTemplate>
            <img src = "images/LOADING.GIF" alt="Loading..."  />
  </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

It will render as

```
<div id="xupProgress">
  <img src = "images/LOADING.GIF" alt="Loading..."  />
</div>
```

Knowing this you can add a style to those pages that permanently hides that DIV:

```
#xupProgress {
    display:none !important
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helps! I originally wanted to hide these from popping up because the page kept jumping to the top every time a user control is loaded (there are about 5 that load with the page), so it jumps back up 5 times. I thought it was the updateprogress causing this behavior, but it still is occurring. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing code flow and page markup. But you can try and workaround it - e.g. temporarily disable page scrolling until last control is loaded etc.

Comment: But that is a different question I believe if that particular problem persists, you should ask it separately.