# How to use UpdateProgress in Master Page and Content Page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an `UpdateProgress` in the master page which appears on any async post back for content pages. Works fine.

In one of the content pages, I have another `UpdateProgress` which runs on `TextChanged` event of a text box. When the async post back occurs, both `UpdateProgress` controls appear.

I have tried using `AssociatedUpdatePanelID` on `UpdateProgress` in the content page, but it's not working. Both still appear.

How can I disable the `UpdateProgress` in the master page for a particular `UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 0):

Set EnablePartialRendering="false" on the ScriptManager, it will in effect disable the AJAX behavior of the UpdatePanel. That way you can put a property in this page to let the content pages to be able to enable/disable async postback way of working this page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager EnablePartialRendering="false"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Just tried this, and still both UpdateProgress controls appearing.

Comment: ok I think this article will help you to solve the problem http://forums.asp.net/t/1037631.aspx?UpdateProgress+and+AssociatedUpdatePanelID+not+working+on+master+page

Comment: I don't want the UpdateProgress in the master page associated with any UpdatePanel. I want that to appear on all async post backs except on certain content page update panels.

Comment: well ok last try set EnablePartialRendering="false" on the ScriptManager, it will in effect disable the AJAX behavior of the UpdatePanel. That way you can put a property in this page to let the content pages to be able to enable/disable async postback way of working this page.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay - I'm really not sure how to do this. Any code examples?

Comment: the example is ok  :) ?

Comment: Thanks, but how will setting `EnablePartialRendering="false"` disable the master page `UpdateProgress` control? How can I disable only the master page `UpdateProgress` after setting this property?

Comment: <asp:UpdateProgress ID="sdfsdfs" runat="server">  </asp:UpdateProgress> and in back sdfsdfs.Visible = false;

Comment: Thanks but that's not going to work for me. `EnablePartialRendering="false"` means there are always full post backs. I simply wanted to disable the master page `UpdateProgress` for a certain `UpdatePanel` but I still want to keep keep partial post backs.

Comment: well good luck  that is last from me:) here Is some themes that can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750051/disabled-updateprogress-for-an-entire-page                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299072/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updateprogress-for-certain-async-postbacks

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone, following JavaScript code did it for me:

```
var disableProgressCtrls = ["MyControl1", "MyControl2"];
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    var updateProgress = $get("MyMasterPageUpdateProgress");
    var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
    if (disableProgressCtrls.indexOf(postBackElement.id) > -1) {
        updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId = 'dummyId';
    } else {
        updateProgress.control._associatedUpdatePanelId = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a surprisingly simple (yet functional and currently working) solution presented here.  It's magic comes when each WebForm-aspx contains AJAX-UpdatePanel(s) and each async-postback defined in the < Triggers > will invoke the UpdateProgress to be shown.  Buttons with PostbackURL will NOT show the UpdateProgress.
The "DisplayAfter" value helps control timing conditions when the image is actually shown.

In the MasterPage, place code (snippet) for the UpdateProgress as follows:

```
<body class="BodyStandard">  // NOTE: my BodyStandard is not relevant to this solution.
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />   
  <div>
     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updprgMain02" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100">
        <ProgressTemplate>    // NOTE:  apply your wait-image spinner, not mine.
           <img src="Images/PleaseWait.gif" alt="Please wait..."/><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Please wait...&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </ProgressTemplate>
     </asp:UpdateProgress>
  </div>
...etc...
```

To place the location of the UpdateProgress when invoked at runtime, use this CSS within the MasterPage styles as follows: NOTE that the control-ID matches the CSS style-name.  ALSO -- the please-wait content is defined within the UpdateProgress  markup and formatted as per the CSS that follows:

```
  #updprgMain02    {
     background: url(Images/PleaseWait.gif) no-repeat 50px 50px;
     padding: 3em;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     position:fixed;
     z-index: 16000;
     top: 10em;
     left: 36em;
     /* IE */
     -moz-opacity: 1.0;
     /* Mozilla */
     opacity: 1.0;
     background-color: gold;
     color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: large;
 }
```

The following is a snapshot of the please-wait image (gif).

[image]