# How to disable UpdateProgress for certain controls in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous, updateprogress

I have a website developed by using ASP.NET. In there lot of ajax request are happening. So I want to display a image when ajax request is happening and hide the image after data loaded. Now this is works fine,

Here what I did so far

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppnlLocation">
<ProgressTemplate>
                  <img src="images/loading.gif" />
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="uppnlLocation">
    <ContentTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddContinents" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddContinents_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">   </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="tvCountries" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvCountries_SelectedNodeChanged"></asp:TreeView>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So in above code when a user select a continent from the dropdown list the countries which belongs that continent will be load to the below treeview. So I want to display a loading image when a user select a continent from the dropdown while loading the countries. Now this is working. But the problem is when user select a tree node in treeview It also shows this progress control image. I don't want to display that image on that action. How to disable it?

I saw a post regarding this.

[Is there a way to disable UpdateProgress for certain async postbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299072/is-there-a-way-to-disable-updateprogress-for-certain-async-postbacks/6301744#6301744)

I implemented it. but then postback is not happening for the dropdown menu.

So how to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Its better just to use the [`DisplayAfter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.displayafter(v=vs.110).aspx) parametre to raise the delay that this is appears because I understand that this just happening so fast. Do not go with complicate javascript solutions just add a delay of 1 or 2 seconds...

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" 
           runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="uppnlLocation" DisplayAfter="2000">
     <ProgressTemplate>
         <img src="images/loading.gif" />
     </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think you mistaken my question. :) In your propose solution it some how appears right? I am talking about a worldwide serving website. In usa this site will load fast. but I dont know how this appear from India. So can not define a fixed time length. So I just want to disable it when I click treeview.

Comment: @Sylar but if in India its take too long to open, more than 5 seconds then you must show a delay or they bealive that is not work....

Answer (score 0):

Well why not just use javascript to force it display none if you are okay with it...
For normal update panel and to call update progress is not always show up. Better to use javascript to pop up update progress rather than using default ways.

Code to pop up Update Progress

```
function showUpdateProgress() {
        var updateProgress = document.getElementById("<%=upProgress.ClientID%>");
        updateProgress.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function HideUpdateProgress() {
        var updateProgress = document.getElementById("<%=upProgress.ClientID%>");
        updateProgress.style.display = 'none';
        Sys.Application.remove_load(HideUpdateProgress);
    }
```

If you are using this way when your job is done in Code behind u need to call javascript to hide the update progress

As per following

In CS file

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Script", "Sys.Application.add_load(HideUpdateProgress);", true);
```

Hope this help you